# Terminal command like Xcopy on mac

Tags: command-line, mac, terminal

Before anyone says rsync, is it possible to use a terminal script (or command line entry) to copy *updated* files only from one place to another on a Mac ie.

```
xcopy "D:\projects" "E:\projects" /d /y /s
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/66401

Comment: This is *related*, but not a dupe of 66401.  The op has asked to NOT consider rsync (although I'd like to know why, it really is a brilliant tool), which is the accepted answer to that other question.  Also, that other question is for Linux in general, and one of the answers there includes what I assume to be a Linux-only option (`--update`) to the `cp` command (that option is not available on my Mac).

Comment: I didn't want to cause confusion by stating it was a Linux question; when it needs to run on a Mac (Mojave). I'm sure rsync is wonderful, only I don't have the admin rights to create a build (long story) so was looking for a simple solution that runs from the terminal.

Comment: cp --update source destination doesn't work on a mac (Mojave)